# Unsigned char * added with int? What does this do?

Tags: c++

I've been working on converting some code from c++ (a language which I can decently read) into Python (a language I can write in well) but came across some lines that left me very confused:

```
unsigned char byte = *(bytes+currentByte);
```

```
float * pF = (float*)(bytes+currentByte);
```

```
std::string str((char*)(bytes+currentByte), numBytes);
```

Now, these lines looked normal enough at first until I realized exactly how the variables were defined:

```
// From the .h file
unsigned char* bytes;
int currentByte;
```

So because I do not understand what exactly would end up happening, I cannot hope to convert the code.

Can anyone please explain to me exactly what adding an `unsigned char *` and an `int` would do? Thank you.

Comment: Read up on [pointer arithmetic](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-8a-pointer-arithmetic-and-array-indexing/).

Comment: What's more suprising to me is the float*

Comment: Pointer arithmetic can be used on any type of pointer, except for `void*`.

Comment: @Stefan if you want to see the rest of the code: https://github.com/nkligang/ccbi2ccb/blob/master/ccbiReader.cpp

Comment: Ah, that makes sense... nice *bit* of code xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*(bytes+currentByte)` is another way of writing `bytes[currentByte]`. It's just address arithmetic and also a little ridiculous when the array notation is clearer to read and write.

The `(float*)(bytes+currentByte)` expression is casting the address of `bytes[currentByte]` to a float pointer or `(float*) &bytes[currentByte]`.

Address arithmetic allows you to transform `bytes[currentByte]` into `currentByte[bytes]` because `*(bytes+currentByte)` is equivalent to `*(currentByte+bytes)`. It's "syntactic sugar" to allow a clearer, or more concise, writing style. These are all equivalent and a very silly programmer trick.

Comment: That's so weird given that they actually do use that exact notation earlier `unsigned char byte = bytes[currentByte];`

Comment: It's worth noting that if you have a pointer to something that's bigger than a char, doing +1 does not increment the pointer "by 1 byte" but does it as "1 element", which means that 2+2 might be different from 4 in that context. So yes, it's confusing, better use the []

Comment: In this case, I feel like the float pointer actually makes sense like this. It would be a float whose pointer would be the same as the pointer stored at (bytes+currentByte), correct? Or would `float * pF = (float*)(bytes+currentByte);` still be the same as `float * pF = (float*)&bytes[currentByte];`?

Comment: @TheElementalofCreation `(float*)(bytes+currentByte)` would be casting the address of `bytes[currentByte]` to a float pointer or `(float*) &bytes[currentByte]`

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh yeah. That's what I meant to put

Comment: Might be worth putting the term "[syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)" somewhere. It's not really "address arithmetic" that allows `x[y] == y[x]`, it's the fact that the syntactic sugar that is the subscript operator translates into exactly `*(x+y)`.

Comment: @TheElementalofCreation If you do byte-wise increments, just make sure you end up at a valid element. Otherwise you'll just be reading/writing garbage between elements.

Comment: @CruzJean Well, I didn't write the c++, but I do know the whole code does actually work.